# Scala Spark use Window function to find max value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
+------------------------|-----+
|               timestamp| zone|
+------------------------+-----+
|    2019-01-01 00:05:00 |    A|
|    2019-01-01 00:05:00 |    A|
|    2019-01-01 00:05:00 |    B|
|    2019-01-01 01:05:00 |    C|
|    2019-01-01 02:05:00 |    B|
|    2019-01-01 02:05:00 |    B|
+------------------------+-----+
```

For each hour I need to count which zone had the most rows and end up with a table that looks like this:

```
+-----|-----+-----+
| hour| zone| max |
+-----+-----+-----+
|    0|    A|    2|
|    1|    C|    1|
|    2|    B|    2|
+-----+-----+-----+
```

My instructions say that I need to use the Window function along with "group by" to find my max count.

I've tried a few things but I'm not sure if I'm close. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Windowing functions` and `group by` with dataframes.

In your case you could use `rank() over(partition by)` window function.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.function._

// first group by hour and zone
    val df_group = data_tms.
      select(hour(col("timestamp")).as("hour"), col("zone"))
      .groupBy(col("hour"), col("zone"))
      .agg(count("zone").as("max"))
// second rank by hour order by max in descending order
    val df_rank = df_group.
      select(col("hour"),
        col("zone"),
        col("max"),
        rank().over(Window.partitionBy(col("hour")).orderBy(col("max").desc)).as("rank"))
// filter by col rank = 1
    df_rank
      .select(col("hour"), 
        col("zone"), 
        col("max"))
      .where(col("rank") === 1)
      .orderBy(col("hour"))
     .show()

/*
+----+----+---+
|hour|zone|max|
+----+----+---+
|   0|   A|  2|
|   1|   C|  1|
|   2|   B|  2|
+----+----+---+
*/
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use 2 subsequent window-functions to get your result:

```
df
  .withColumn("hour",hour($"timestamp"))
  .withColumn("cnt",count("*").over(Window.partitionBy($"hour",$"zone")))
  .withColumn("rnb",row_number().over(Window.partitionBy($"hour").orderBy($"cnt".desc)))
  .where($"rnb"===1)
  .select($"hour",$"zone",$"cnt".as("max"))
```

Comment: I like it, but am wondering why `row_number` not `rank`?

Comment: this is a very elegant solution. I tried it and it worked perfectly. I marked Chema's as correct just he answered first (and of course his response worked as well).

Comment: @JacekLaskowski to get 1 single row per hour, but this of course depends on the requirements, you could also use `rank` if you are ok to have 2 rows with same counts

Comment: @b-ryce to help a bit the conversation about how to choose between multiple Spark answers, and borrowing them from the software world you can evaluate a Spark program/answer based on principles such as performance, scalability/modularity, and finally maintainability. In our case, we can evaluate the Spark performance considering two measures, execution plan and execution time. The maintainability depends on the code structure and size. Maintainable code is considered the one that complies with best practices/design patterns. These are some of the major factors to choose between Spark programs.